# ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal en estos condicionales de JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, condiciones, bucles

Estoy empezando con javascript y me toca hacer un código que desde los datos ingresados mediante un `prompt` recorra un `array` y que muestre un `alert` de bienvenida en caso de encontrar los nombres Juan o Mario o que por el contrario muestre otro `alert` distinto de ausencia en la lista ingresada, luego todos los nombres del `array` ingresados los tengo que incluir en una lista `ol` de `html`. debo tener algunos errores, porque los condicionales no me funcionan, gracias de antemano a quien pueda darme una mano e instruirme un poco. Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora:

```js
nombres = prompt("Ingrese los nombres");

var nombre = nombres.split(",");

for (elemento of nombre) {
  if ((elemento === 'programar') || (elemento === 'programacion')) {
    continue;
    alert('que bueno que te guste la programacion');

  } else {

    alert("Que lástima que no te guste la programación");

  }
}

var item = document.createElement("LI");
var crearelemento = document.createTextNode(elemento); //Guarda el elemento en una variable, crea un nodo de texto con el elemento.   
item.appendChild(crearelemento); //añade el ítem al elemento   
document.getElementsByClassName('lista')[0].appendChild(item); //adjunta el nodo item al nodo padre id lista
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2 id="modificar"></h2>
  <article>
    <ol class="lista">

    </ol>
  </article>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @BetaM ya esta arreglado, pero no me funciona de todos modos ¿Alguna sugerencia? Gracias de antemano

Comment: estas buscando en `hobbies` , pero no lo tienes declarado, tienes que declararlo con anterioridad para poder buscar en el.

Comment: @Richard Ahí lo edite, se me había pasado un for. Esta bien ahora ahí lo estaría buscando en la variable nombre.

Comment: porque hay un continue; antes del alert, dentro del if????? porque este codigo es exactamente igual al de tu pregunta anterior? cual es el error que recibis?

Comment: Que tiene que ver la explicacion de tu problema, con el codigo propuesto????

Comment: @gbianch el error es distinto al anterior, no me toma el if, siempre el resultado es else, es decir, por mas que digite programación o programar el resultado siempre es else. No se en que estoy fallando.

Comment: Si te refieres al alert, pusiste un continue antes de él, por lo que se salta esa iteración completa

Answer (score 0):

tu problema actual es el uso de `continue` antes del `alert`, puedes leer [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) un poco mas sobre como usarlo

**Explicación rápida:**

El `continue` se utiliza en ciclos como `for` y `while`, para indicar al ciclo que no debe ejecutar el resto de líneas de código en esa iteración.

- En el caso del `for` pasara a su siguiente valor normalmente representado con `i`
- En el caso de `while` ejecutará nuevamente la condición.

ejemplos:

**`for`**

```
const array = [1,2,3,4];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // condición que evitara le ejcución del resto del código
    if (array[i] === 3) { 
        continue; // evita que se imprima 3
    }
    
    console.log(array[i]);
}
```

**`while`**

```
let num = 0
while (num <= 6) {
    console.log(num);
    // si la condición se cumple
    // incrementa en 4 y no ejecuta el resto del codigo
    // despues del continue
    if (num === 2) {
        num+=4;
        continue
    }
    num+=2;
}
```

### Tu código sin el error

```js
nombres = prompt("Ingrese los nombres");

var nombre = nombres.split(",");

for (elemento of nombre) {
  if ((elemento === 'programar') || (elemento === 'programacion')) {
    alert('que bueno que te guste la programacion');

  } else {

    alert("Que lástima que no te guste la programación");

  }
}

var item = document.createElement("LI");
var crearelemento = document.createTextNode(elemento); //Guarda el elemento en una variable, crea un nodo de texto con el elemento.   
item.appendChild(crearelemento); //añade el ítem al elemento   
document.getElementsByClassName('lista')[0].appendChild(item); //adjunta el nodo item al nodo padre id lista
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2 id="modificar"></h2>
  <article>
    <ol class="lista">

    </ol>
  </article>



</body>

</html>
```